# Close dynamically created form with dynamic button

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm trying to close a dynamically created form with a dynamic button (this is the simplest of my jobs, I am also adding other buttons to do other jobs but I figured this is a good place to start). 
As of now I can create the form, button and the click event for that button, but I don't know what to add within the click event function to close the host of that button. I am guessing I can somehow access the buttons parent through the click function? Or maybe pass the form control as an argument in the function? Any help is appreciated!

```
        //Create form
        Snapshot snapshot = new Snapshot();
        snapshot.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

        //Create save button
        Button saveButton = new Button();
        saveButton.Text = "Save Screenshot";
        saveButton.Location = new Point(snapshot.Width - 100, snapshot.Height - 130);
        saveButton.Click += new EventHandler(saveButton_buttonClick);

        //Create exit button
        Button exitButton = new Button();
        exitButton.Text = "Exit";
        exitButton.Location = new Point(snapshot.Width - 100, snapshot.Height - 100);

        //Add all the controls and open the form
        snapshot.Controls.Add(saveButton);
        snapshot.Controls.Add(exitButton);
        snapshot.ShowDialog();
```

And my click event function looks pretty much normal:

```
    void saveButton_buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Unfortunately I don't know what to add for the function to work! Thanks in advance for any help someone can give me! I feel like this should be a straight-forward problem to solve but I haven't been able to figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's certainly possible to do this with a named function, it's generally simpler to just use an anonymous function in cases like this:

```
Snapshot snapshot = new Snapshot();
snapshot.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

//Create save button
Button saveButton = new Button();
saveButton.Text = "Save Screenshot";
saveButton.Location = new Point(snapshot.Width - 100, snapshot.Height - 130);
saveButton.Click += (_,args)=>
{
    SaveSnapshot();
};

//Create exit button
Button exitButton = new Button();
exitButton.Text = "Exit";
exitButton.Location = new Point(snapshot.Width - 100, snapshot.Height - 100);
exitButton.Click += (_,args)=>
{
    snapshot.Close();
};

//Add all the controls and open the form
snapshot.Controls.Add(saveButton);
snapshot.Controls.Add(exitButton);
snapshot.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Wonderful. This actually suits my purposes much more succinctly. The help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a lambda method:

```
Button exitButton = new Button();
exitButton.Text = "Exit";
exitButton.Click += (s, e) => { shapshot.Close(); };
```