# Dynamic creation of form with button and closing this form while clicking button

Tags: c#, winforms

On `form1`, I have `registerButton` that create new `registerForm` with an `acceptButton` on it. Both dynamically created:

```
private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    registerButton.Enabled = false;
    Form registrationForm = new Form();
    registrationForm.Text = "Register new account";
    registrationForm.Visible = true;
    Button createButton = new Button();
    createButton.Text = "Accept";
    registrationForm.Controls.Add(createButton);
    createButton.Click+= new EventHandler(createButton_Click);        
}
```

How can I close `registerForm` after clicking `acceptButton` without closing the `form1`?

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what *dynamic creation* means?

Comment: Creating dynamic form will lead to lots of mess if doing with partial knowledge...so better create an simple div and make its visibility hidden.on clicking register button open this div as a dialog.Both are of same functionalities.

Comment: I know that, but in my project will be many hidden forms.

Comment: i havent seen this before
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793490/close-dynamically-created-form-with-dynamic-button?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've lost the reference to the registration form instance.  But you can always get it back from the *sender* argument that's passed to the Click event handler.  Like this:

```
    private void registrationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var btn = (Control)sender;
        btn.FindForm().Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For your code (which I don't recommend to use) fix will be

```
createButton.Click += (s,e) => registrationForm.Close();
```

When you attach this lambda as event handler, you have opportunity to capture `registrationForm` instance in a closure. Thus form instance will be available when click event will happen, and you will be able to close this form.

---

Better approach: instead of adding button dynamically to form, place this button statically in designer and attach click event handler which will close the form:

```
private void acceptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

Usage of registration form will be simple as:

```
private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form registrationForm = new Form();
    registrationForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: This form can't disappear before I click the button.

Comment: @pochmurnik who talks about disappearing of form? Have you tried the code?

Comment: Yes, after clicking registerButton, form only blink. Isn't it because of the scope of _using_?

Comment: @pochmurnik yes, sorry. `using` is useful for dialog forms (which are displayed with `ShowDialog()` - it disposes form just after you close it. But in case of simple `Show()` you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

Add `this.Close()` at the click event of `acceptButton`.
You can attach an event to it dynamically. While creating the button, do `acceptButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(accepButton_click);` and create matching function or press Tab twice after doing the +=.

Comment: This will close both forms